# go routine blocking the others one

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

The following code run forever instead of stopping one second after the beginning.
The go routine with the infinite loop seems to prevent the other one from sending to the timeout channel. Is that normal ?

```
 func main(){
   timeout:=make(chan int)
   go func(){
      time.SLeep(time.Second)
      timeout<-1
    }()

    res:=make(chan int)
    go func(){
        for{
        }
        res<-1
    }()
    select{
        case<-timeout:
            fmt.Println("timeout")
        case<-res:
            fmt.Println("res")
    }
}
```

Comment: This SO q/a answers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413510/why-is-this-go-code-blocking?rq=1

sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

The current implementation uses cooperative scheduling among goroutines. This means that a goroutine must hand off execution to the scheduler for another goroutine to run. There is hope in the future to use a preemptive scheduler which will not have this limitation.

Goroutines yield to the scheduler when any of the following happens (may not be a comprehensive list):

- unbuffered chan send/recv
- syscalls (includes file/network reads and writes)
- memory allocation
- time.Sleep() is called
- runtime.Gosched() is called

The last one allows you to manually yield to the scheduler when you have a very processor intensive loop. I have never found a need for it because just about everything I use has enough communication (channels or system io) that my programs never get stuck.

There is also GOMAXPROCS which you will probably hear as a solution to this. While it would allow all your goroutines to run by putting them in different threads, the garbage collector would eventually try to run and stop the world. When it stops the world, no goroutines are allowed to run and if the high cpu goroutines never yield, the GC will block goroutines forever but never run.

Comment: Just curious: how can preemptive scheduler be implemented without OS support (and consequently without OS threads)? Well, I think it *may* be possible to implement some kind of preemptive multitasking in custom virtual machine, but it likely should be interpreting-only, and, consequently, horribly slow. And it is obviously a no-way for Go.

Comment: Judging by this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/golang-dev/pre-emptive/golang-dev/vtrWpvf8nMA/PPs5Eqpk-VgJ it looks like there's planned to be a monitor OS thread that handles it.

Comment: If you know the scheduler is cooperative (which we do) then ensuring that programs cooperate is not hard. This is a considerable benefit to the runtime implementers because pre-emptive scheduling is usually less efficient, because the context needing saving cannot be optimised. The Transputer followed the cooperative principle and achieved incredibly fast context switching times (similar to procedure call overheads) ... as does the modern Occam-Pi compiler (from Kent).

Answer (score 3):

That's because with a single processor, your second goroutine will busy-wait (monopolize the processor by looping and never letting the other goroutine run).

It works if you put, for example, a `time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)` inside the for loop:

http://play.golang.org/p/M4jeckcmov

Comment: Thx Puerkito. There is a long answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413510/why-is-this-go-code-blocking)