# Loop in goroutine hangs program

Tags: go

Why does the following program hang when the `time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond)` is commented out?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "sync/atomic"

func main() {
    var ops uint64 = 0
    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                atomic.AddUint64(&ops, 1)
                time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond)
            }
        }()
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    opsFinal := atomic.LoadUint64(&ops)
    fmt.Println("ops:", opsFinal)
}
```

Second question, why does [running this program in the sandbox](https://play.golang.org/p/lnl5qxRfit) result in "process took too long"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because goroutine is cooperative (not fully preemptive) task, and the context switch only happen when there's some IO, system call, `time.Sleep()`, or calling large function which have to extend the stack.

Reference:

- [Go Routine Blocking the Other One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953269/go-routine-blocking-the-others-one)
- [Preemption since Go 1.2](https://golang.org/doc/go1.2#preemption)

Your `atomic.AddUint64(&ops, 1)` is small function which does not have to extend stack. so the context switch never occurs.

Since main thread is also a goroutine, it does not acquire context switch, and sleeps forever.

There's [an open issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10958) to make golang preemptive in tight loop, but not yet solved.

More useful references:

- [A pitfall of golang scheduler](http://www.sarathlakshman.com/2016/06/15/pitfall-of-golang-scheduler)
- [golang scheduler is not preemptive - it's cooperative?](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11462)