# Golang: writing to a variable has no effect in a goroutine if immediately followed by a `for{}` loop

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, goroutine, memory-model

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var x = 0
    go func() {
        x = 1
        for {
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(5000 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("%d", x)
}
```

Why does the above code print `0`?

If you add anything before or in the `for{}`, for example, `runtime.Gosched()`, `print(x)`, it will print `1` as expected.

Is it related to write barrier / happened-before, or? I'm totally confused.

I made the other goroutine sleep for 5 seconds before printing the value. Isn't it enough time for the write to sync / cache to flush / ...?

Comment: The output of the program is unspecified because the program has a data race.  The [memory model](https://go.dev/ref/mem) does not require the compiler to include the statement `x = 1` in the compiled program.

Comment: @CeriseLimón so basically, since there is no happened-before guarantee, the compiler can readjust the order of code, and make `for{}` happen before `x=1`?

Comment: Is this problem only related to golang compiler (the assembly it produces)? Or is it possible that even if golang compiler doesn't do any "optimization", CPU can also perform out-of-order execution and execute `for{}` before `x=1`? Finally, how to fix this problem (I know using mutex will fix this problem, any other simpler ways)? Thanks very much

Comment: If you want to block a goroutine use `select {}`, or a channel op, don't use empty `for {}`.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I understand. It's just a contrived example, to reproduce a problem I encountered in another piece of more complex code

Comment: The compiler can reorder the code as you noted.  Because the write to variable `x` does  not happen before any uses of `x`, the compiler can also omit the write.

Comment: @Kevin but the contrived example is fixed if you use `select {}` instead of empty `for {}`, no? So if your "more complex code" doesn't use a [tight loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53929956/965900) then you *may* have a problem that's different from the one in the question.

Comment: @Kevin also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852429/loop-in-goroutine-hangs-program

Comment: Right, `select{}` can fix it. I was just curious how it could happen if I write code this way, just to improve my understanding of golang 

Comment: To guarantee that the program prints 1, the program must ensure that `x = 1` happens before the print statement.  The switch from `for{}` to `select {}` does not fix the data race.

Comment: I see, thanks @CeriseLimón for pointing it out. Seems like we have to use one of the mechanisms in `Synchronization` section of https://go.dev/ref/mem to fix the data race. That is, channel or lock. cc @mkopriva

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706600/golang-writing-to-a-variable-has-no-effect-in-a-goroutine-if-immediately-follow#comment124997028_70706600), Cerise.

```
~ go tool compile -S main.go
...
"".main.func1 STEXT nosplit size=3 args=0x0 locals=0x0 funcid=0x0
        0x0000 00000 (main.go:10)       TEXT    "".main.func1(SB), NOSPLIT|NEEDCTXT|ABIInternal, $0-0
        0x0000 00000 (main.go:10)       FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
        0x0000 00000 (main.go:10)       FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
        0x0000 00000 (main.go:12)       XCHGL   AX, AX
        0x0001 00001 (main.go:1)        JMP     0
        0x0000 90 eb fd
```

Seems like golang compiler indeed deleted the `x = 1` statement in the assembly (should be `main.go:11`).

We really need to keep [The Go Memory Model](https://go.dev/ref/mem) and [Happens Before](https://go.dev/ref/mem#tmp_2) in mind when programming.